# How to change a reference pointer to another object

Tags: java, oop

I've been reading a introduction to java book *(Core Java SE 9, not that it's important)* and it mentioned that you couldn't write a method that changes an object reference to something else.

The code they've provided as an example of what doesn't work is as follows. My question is what is the alternative to this I could use if I wanted to acomplish the same results.

```
public class EvilManager {
...
   public void replaceWithZombie(Employee e) {
     e = new Employee("", 0);
   }
}
```

sorry I may have screwed up some of the exact nomanclature, I'm newish but I'm trying hard

Comment: Return the new `Employee` object, so the caller can get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take the object at class level.

```
public class EvilManager {
   private Employee emp; // reference to it can be changed from anywhere within the class (or even outside if you change access modifier)

   public void initEmployee() {
      emp = new Employee("1", 0);
   }

   public void replaceWithZombie(Employee e) {
      emp = new Employee("2", 0); // reference changed
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This assignment does actually change the value of the parameter `e` but only within the method. It does not have any influence on an actual parameter. This is because Java uses call by value.

You could however change the object itself (if it is mutable) and this change would be visible outside. Something like:

```
e.setName("abc");
```